# Modify Duplicates Python 2.5

Tags: python, python-2.5

I have first of all:

```
list_= [{u'name': 'example1', u'type': 1L},
        {u'name': 'example1', u'type': 2L},
        {u'name': 'example2', u'type': 2L},
        {u'name': 'example2', u'type': 3L},
        {u'name': 'example2', u'type': 4L},
        {u'name': 'example3', u'type': 1L}]
```

And i want to show with the list above:

```
example1 [1, 2]
example2 [2, 3, 4]
example3 [1]
```

I just tried to do something like:

```
        for x in list:
            p.add((x["name"], x["type"]), "%s [%s]" % (x["name"], x["type"]))
```

But that will just show all entries

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict    
result = defaultdict(set)
for d in _list:
    result[d['name']].add(d['type'])
```

Comment: After editing the input list to add the missing '2', I verified that this produces a default dict with the essentiall information requested.